# A number puzzle

Tags: mathematics

So i got a letter in the mail today, it seems to be a number puzzle, i don’t know the rules but i think i can guess them.
Use all numbers once to create a correct formula.
Though I might be wrong, please let me know if you have seen this before and if you know what is.

Obviously you can try to solve it, i know i will when i’ve got some time today.

In your awnser please explain how you interperted the letter and put your solution in spoiler tags (i would like to see different interpetations and try to solve them my self as well)

[image]

Comment: Is there any more context to the letter? What does generating a numerical answer then lead to? Are you expected to do something with the answer? Also, I really can't help but notice that it looks very much like a T with a bit across the middle.

Comment: There is nothing more known, i actually don’t even know if we were meant to solve it that way. And yes the T shape can’t be missed. So it might well be there’s more to this.

Comment: Several other peoples in the street/city block got the same letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found one potential solution, assuming I understand the rules.  I think the idea is to make a viable formula using each number and each symbol once (except for the symbols which mean the same thing)

> **8.2 x 5 - 9√4 + 37 = 6 / 10%**

which simplifies to

> 41 - 9(2) + 37 = 6 / 0.1
>  41 - 18 + 37 = 60
>  60 = 60

Comment: What about the T though?